# Right way to clean up a temporary folder in Python class

Tags: python, destructor, temporary-directory

I am creating a class in which I want to generate a temporary workspace of folders that will persist for the life of the object and then be removed.  I am using `tempfile.mkdtemp()` in the `def __init__` to create the space, but I have read that I can't rely on `__del__` being called.

I am wanting something like this:

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.tempfolder = tempfile.mkdtemp()

  def ... #other stuff

  def __del__(self):
    if os.path.exists(self.tempfolder): shutil.rmtree(self.tempfolder)
```

Is there another/better way to handle this clean up?  I was reading about `with`, but it appears to only be helpful within a function.

Comment: I think the only reliable solutions will always involve doing the clean-up explicitly. I don't think the _reliable automatic clean-up_ solution you envisage in your question is possible.

Comment: @PedroRomano false: Python's context managers are exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @katrielalex: even context managers need to be explicitly entered.

Comment: @PedroRomano yes -- but you _always_ need to e.g. open a file. The point of a context manager is that it handles _cleaning up_.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Caveat: you can never *guarantee* that the temp folder will be deleted, because the user could always hard kill your process and then it can't run anything else.

That said, do

```
temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    <some code>
finally:
    shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

---

Since this is a very common operation, Python has a special way to encapsulate "do something, execute code, clean up": a *context manager*. You can write your own as follows:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def make_temp_directory():
    temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        yield temp_dir
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

and use it as

```
with make_temp_directory() as temp_dir:
    <some code>
```

(Note that this uses the `@contextlib.contextmanager` shortcut to make a context manager. If you want to implement one the original way, you need to make a custom class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods; the `__enter__` would create and return the temp directory and the `__exit__` delete it.

Comment: Can the context manager persist my temporary folder for the life of the object?  It looks like it would remove the folder once I leave the 'with' statement.  I guess I could pass the folder into my object as a parameter, but I was hoping to encapsulate the temporary folder within the class.

Comment: The _definition_ of the `with` statement is that it closes the object when you leave it. If you want your temp directory to close somewhere else, you need to close it explicitly there and handle exceptions yourself.

Comment: I like how this works now that I have refactored my code to use the contextmanager.

Comment: The context manager works fine for me, but I had to add a try: finally: around the yield or otherwise it wouldn't clean up if the code using the temp dir raises an exception. Might be documented somewhere or might be different between python versions, but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: That behavior is [documented](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager): "If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use a `try...except...finally` statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place."

Comment: Note that Python 3.2 added `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` which does the same thing that this answer shows.  For 3.2 and newer I would use the library module code; for older Python versions I would use this code, but I'd rename the function to `TemporaryDirectory()` and document that it is similar to the 3.2 code.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html

Answer (score 30):

A nice way to deal with temporary files and directories is via a context manager. This is how you can use [tempfile.TemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) or [tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) -- once you've exited the `with` statement (via normal exit, return, exception, or anything else) the file/directory and it's contents will be removed from the filesystem.

For Python 3.2+, this is built in as [tempfile.TemporaryDirectory](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory):

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    ... do stuff ...
```

For earlier Python versions you can easily create your own context manager to do exactly the same thing. The differences here from @katrielalex answer are the passing of args to `mkdtemp()` and the try/finally block to make sure the directory gets cleaned up if an exception is raised.

```
import contextlib
import shutil

@contextlib.contextmanager
def temporary_directory(*args, **kwargs):
    d = tempfile.mkdtemp(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield d
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(d)


# use it
with temporary_directory() as temp_dir:
    ... do stuff ...
```

Note that if your process is hard-killed (eg. `kill -9`) then the directories won't get cleaned up.

Answer (score 13):

I somewhat experimented with this and I am quite confident that, **if you cannot use a context manager**, the best solution as of this posting is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tempfolder = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    
    …

    def __del__(self):
        self.tempfolder.cleanup()
```

(Some conditional in `__del__` may be reasonable if you cannot ensure `__init__` to be called.)

Now, except from using the newer `TemporaryDirectory` instead of `mkdtemp`, this is not much different from what you were doing. Why do I still think this is the best you can do? Well, I tested several scenarios of program exit and similar (all on Linux) and:

- I could not find a scenario where the temporary folder was not deleted even though I would expect that Python could decide that the respective instance of `MyClass` was not needed anymore. Automatic deletion happens as early as Python’s garbage collecting heuristics allow.
- You can “help” the garbage collector with `del myinstance` and `gc.collect()`. Mind that `del` only [decreases the reference count](https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/), so this does not ensure that garbage collection can happen and `__del__` is called.
- If you really want to ensure deletion (of the temporary directory), you can explicitly call `myinstance.__del__()`. If you can do this, you can probably also make `MyClass` itself a context manager.
- The only case where the temporary folder persisted was when I hard-killed Python from the operating system – in which case I do not see how any solution within Python would work.
- `atexit` (as suggested, e.g., by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54817328/2127008)) does not improve the situation: Either deletion happens without `atexit` anyway, or it does not happen even with `atexit`.

Comment: this is the correct answer.  OP stipulates he is making a `class` with a temp workspace that `will persist for the life of the object`.  this is what `__del__` was made for.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative using `contextlib` is to make your object closable, and use the [`closing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) context manager.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tempfolder = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    def do_stuff():
        pass

    def close(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.tempfolder):
            shutil.rmtree(self.tempfolder)
```

Then with the context manager:

```
from contextlib import closing

with closing(MyClass()) as my_object:
    my_object.do_stuff()
```

Comment: I know a lot changed on context managers since this answer was posted, but wouldn’t it be easier to just add `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to `MyClass` to make it useable as a context manager itself?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft as I say, it's an alternative. If you implement `__enter__` and `__exit__` you have to implement both. As the `__init__` serves the same purpose, `__enter__` will be empty. Using the `close` paradigm is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have noted that you can use a contextmanager or require your users to explicitly call some type of clean up function. These are great to do if you can. However, sometimes there's no where to hook up this cleanup because you are inside a large application and you are nested multiple layers down, and no one above you has cleanup methods or context managers.

In that case, you can use atexit: https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html

```
import atexit

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.tempfolder = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    atexit.register(shutil.rmtree, self.tempfolder)

  def ... #other stuff
```

Comment: If `atexit` gets to be called, then `__del__` as in the question should be too. At least in comparison to `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory`, I failed to find a scenario where `atexit` improves the situation (also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537942/2127008)).

Comment: On top, this solution prevents the garbage collector from deleting the temporary directory early and every way to include directory deletion in `__del__` as well will lead to one of the following problems as soon as there are multiple instances of `MyClass`: 1) If `rmtree` is not unregistered from `atexit`, an error is raised upon exiting if one instance is cleaned up early. 2) If unregistered, `atexit` cannot delete a second instance of the class upon exiting. 3) If registered with a method, the garbage collector cannot clean up early because `atexit` still references the instance.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by [Bluewind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953022/bluewind) you have to make sure to wrap the yield portion of the context manager inside of a try: finally statement otherwise any exceptions will not really be handled correctly inside of the context manager.

From [Python 2.7 docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tempfile.html)

> At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited. If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use a try...except...finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place. If an exception is trapped merely in order to log it or to perform some action (rather than to suppress it entirely), the generator must reraise that exception. Otherwise the generator context manager will indicate to the with statement that the exception has been handled, and execution will resume with the statement immediately following the with statement.

Also if you are using Python 3.2+ you should check out [this little gem](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/tempfile.html) which has all of the above wrapped up nicely for you

> tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(suffix='', prefix='tmp', dir=None)
>
> This function creates a temporary directory using mkdtemp() (the supplied arguments are passed directly to the underlying function). The resulting object can be used as a context manager (see With Statement Context Managers). On completion of the context (or destruction of the temporary directory object), the newly created temporary directory and all its contents are removed from the filesystem.
>
> The directory name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned object.
>
> The directory can be explicitly cleaned up by calling the cleanup() method.
>
> New in version 3.2.

Comment: **Python 3 `cleanup()` in `with`:** be aware the `cleanup()` method is something **USELESS INSIDE CONTEXT MANAGER `with`**, since it's a method of `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()` - which, ***if** used in the context manager*, returns a *`string`* ! (not the object itself). On top of that `tempfile.TemporaryDirectory.cleanup()` **does not just "clean" its contents** it also removes the directory itself!